# Javascript continuous function

Tags: javascript

I want to write a function that continuously renders the data from a form.  I am creating a form that has a price and sales tax and it outputs total price.  Upon editing information I want my function to automatically update the total price without clicking a button.  For example if something cost $10 with a 5% tax the price will be $10.50. If I change the price to $5 on the form I would want the total price to automatically update. I'm looking for some guidance to approaching this.

Comment: It's difficult to give you a specific answer without seeing some code and what you've tried already.  All I can tell you is that you need to watch for onchange events and then re-calculate your form.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried to use EventListeners, or a global Timer?

Comment: Listen to the correct events (change, keyup, etc) and perform the desired operation in response to those events.

Comment: You can search **Update form with Jquery**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with [onchange Event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp)

I wrote this basic example: http://jsfiddle.net/uja7bxmm/

Html:

```
<form>
    Price: <input type="text" id="price" onchange= "calculate()"/> 
    Tax: <input type="text" id="tax" onchange= "calculate()"/>

</form>

Total: <span id="total"/>
```

Javascript:

```
function calculate() {
var price =parseInt(document.getElementById("price").value,10);
    var tax= parseInt(document.getElementById("tax").value,10);
    if (!isNaN(price) && !isNaN(tax)) {
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = (100+tax)*price/100; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response but you guys are awesome!